# calling serverStatus() on mongodb replicas returns the same information

Tags: mongodb

Calling `db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } )` on mongodb replicas, one would expect to get different metrics from the primary, eg number of connections, replications operations, etc.

However, no matter which node I query, I get the exact same result.

How do I accurately get per node metrics, like connections? It seems like they are being fetched from the primary instead.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. it was the driver. it was passing information to the primary. i had to modify the connect string to make it talk directly to the replica only.